# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: php, html, apache, virtualhost, laragon

Any have some ideas?

[image]

```
 <VirtualHost *:80> 
DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/monetize/public/"
ServerName monetize.app
ServerAlias *.monetize.app
<Directory "C:/laragon/www/monetize/public/">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Apache 2.4.27
Laragon full 3.1.4
Windows 8.1
DNS i set in internet options 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

[image]

Comment: Did you pay for the domain? If you did so recently, you might need to wait for it to propagate in the network.

Comment: If that's not a real domain then you need to add it to your `hosts` file.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone
https://image.prntscr.com/image/2TiQ7E-QRwCACBH7JO-oag.png if i go 127.0.0.1 that work, only virtual hosts not work, why? https://image.prntscr.com/image/AkFb8AVaT6SDMh6RXqg_eg.png

Comment: @ArtursJerjomins See https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i check all, and none work to me. :(

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an entry to your `hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1 monetize.app
localhost monetize.app
```

Comment: i have
    127.0.0.1      monetize.app         #laragon magic!
https://image.prntscr.com/image/2TiQ7E-QRwCACBH7JO-oag.png

Comment: What happens when you `ping monetize.app`?

Comment: OK, so it's not an Apache problem but rather a `hosts` problem. Follow [these](https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot) **step by step**.

Comment: You have some idea? :(